# Power series that diverges in specified number of points on the circle of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I want to construct a complex power series with the radius of convergence $R=1$ that diverges in:

1) $k$ points on the circle $\{|z|=1\}$.

2) countable number of points on the circle

I have already crafted series that converges on the whole circle and diverges on the whole circle.

Can anybody help with the problem?

Update: I have googled a series $\sum{\frac{z^{kn}}{kn}}$ that is an answer for 1). Though I still need help for the countable case.

Comment: Hint: Can you imagine a solution to 1) for $k=1$. It will help you for general $k$ (think about "rotating").

Comment: @martini, I have updated the question. My problem is about DIVergence.

Comment: what were your functions that converge and diverge on the whole circle?

Answer (score 6):

For part 1), we can use [Abel's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) to prove $\log(1-z)$ converges everywhere on the boundary except at $z=1$. I believe now taking $f(z) = \log(1-z^k)$ should do.

For part 2)

The generating function for the number of partitions of $n$ has a countable number of singularities and to deal with that, Hardy, Ramanujan and Littlewood came up with the [Circle Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_circle_method), which they used to determine the asymptotic behaviour of the partition number.

But, I suppose there is an easier example, as this is homework.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for (2), take a sequence of points $z_k$ on the circle converging to $1$, say, and try
putting together series that diverge at each $z_k$.