# Convergence of power series on boundary:

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to solve the following tasks:

- Find a power series with radius of convergence $1$ such that it converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ **except** for $z = 1$ **and** $z = -i$.

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ would be an example of a power series which diverges on the boundary only at $z = 1$, and you could for example change this to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n}$ such that it also diverges for $z = -1$, but how can I generalise this idea?

Also, according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122881/power-series-that-diverges-in-specified-number-of-points-on-the-circle-of-conver) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{kn}}{kn}$ may be a way to create k-points of divergence, but it's unclear to me where these points are on the unit circle.

Comment: substituting $w=z/i$ (which means rotating the function) in the first example gives an example that converges except at $i$ and then summing the two, gives the required example; more generally for any finite set on the unit circle, one can use the first series rotated appropriately and then sum the examples; it is a tricky problem to characterize all infinite circle sets $E$ for which one has powers series converging except at each point of $E$

Comment: Ahh thankyou, I was missing the idea of summing several series together!

Comment: @happy to be of help